# Excel daemon instance: Access VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

This problem has consumed a lot of my time now. Everytime I run code from access to launch excel read file location and then open the excel on that file location, make changes and close. I see that this leaves an orphan excel process. I have tried all ways of referencing and possible solutions suggested out on internet, but nothing to help. My code as below. Any help or suggestions would be great:

```
Public Sub productdetailprinter()

Dim i As Double
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim recSet As Recordset
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tableName As String
Dim recTable As Recordset
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim k As Integer
Dim r As Integer
Dim intformat As Integer
Dim wrksht As Worksheet
Dim wrkbk As Workbook
Dim filelocation As String
Dim xl As Excel.Application


Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set recSet = dbs.OpenRecordset("tbl_formList")
Set wrkbk = xl.Workbooks.Open("<location>")
Set wrksht = wrkbk.Worksheets("databaselinks")
filelocation = wrksht.Range("C5").Value

wrkbk.Close
xl.Quit
Set wrksht = Nothing
Set wrkbk = Nothing
Set xl = Nothing
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True
xl.Workbooks.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
xl.Workbooks.Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(filelocation & "\product_detail.xlsx")
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("details")
xl.Workbooks.Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
xl.Workbooks.Application.DisplayAlerts = True

ws.Range("B3", Range("B3").End(xlDown)).Select
xl.Selection.Clear
ws.Range("C3", Range("C3").End(xlDown)).Select
xl.Selection.Clear
ws.Range("D3", Range("D3").End(xlDown)).Select
xl.Selection.Clear

i = ws.Columns("B").End(xlDown).Row
i = i + 1
Do Until recSet.EOF

'code lines

recSet.MoveNext
Loop

ws.Save
wb.Close
xl.Quit
Set xl = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing
recTable.Close
recSet.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: [Indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) has many benefits and should be second nature to a professional programmer.

Comment: There is no need to quit Excel and create another instance. You can just continue to use it.  Normally, setting ws and wb to nothing would happen before disposing off xl. Since your Excel instance is visible, you should be able to tell when it closes.

Answer (score 0):

You must close the objects in exact reverse order:

```
' Also:
Dim rng As Excel.Range

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True

Set wrkbk = xl.Workbooks.Open("<location>")
Set wrksht = wrkbk.Worksheets("databaselinks")
Set rng = wrksht.Range("C5")
filelocation = rng.Value

Set rng = Nothing
Set wrksht = Nothing
wrkbk.Close
Set wrkbk = Nothing
xl.Quit
Set xl = Nothing
```

This is tested and works at me:

```
Public Sub EditWorkSheet()

    Dim xls     As Excel.Application
    Dim wkb     As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wks     As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim rng     As Excel.Range

    Dim Column  As Integer

    Set xls = New Excel.Application
    Set wkb = xls.Workbooks.Open("c:\test\test.xlsx")
    Set wks = wkb.Worksheets(1)

    Set rng = wks.Range("C5")
    rng.Value = 4

    wkb.Close True, "c:\test\test1.xlsx"

    Set rng = Nothing
    Set wks = Nothing
    Set wkb = Nothing

    xls.Quit

    Set xls = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav, I changed the code to close in reverse order. It still leaves excel instance at the end.
Also i observed that everytime i run the code in debug mode it runs properly but when i run, it fails at Set rng = wrksht.Range("C5").. do you also have any suggestion for that please?

Comment: As @MikeC noted, you should also take care to open Excel _once_ only. See edited answer with simplified example.

Comment: what error message do you get when it fails at `Set rng = wrksht.Range("C5")`?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for proposed solutions. After spending 4 hours on this.. I realized that vba wasnt happy with the way I was referencing the ranges.

ws.Range("B3", Range("B3").End(xlDown)).Select
should be referenced as 
ws.Range(ws.Range("B3"), ws.Range("B3").End(xlDown)).Select

It works like a charm.. Excel instances die and no more errors.
Hope this saves someones time out there.

Thank You